# Running SonarQube Analysis twice marks all previous issues as removed

Tags: android, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm analysing an Android project, triggering the analysis from a Jenkins build process.

I installed Sonar (5.1), MySQL (5.5.43), SonarQube Runner (2.4), and the SonarQube plugin (2.2.1) for Jenkins (1.617).

During the build I trigger the analysis with the following properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=${PROJECT_NAME}
sonar.projectName=${PROJECT_NAME}
sonar.projectVersion=${PROJECT_VERSION}

sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.java.binaries=build

sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.android.lint.report=lint-report.xml
```

As sonar.profile is deprecated I meant to set it on the project after the first analysis.

I run the build, and it runs the analysis. I go to `my.sonar.ip:9000` and there I have my project, with all those ugly issues.
I go to `Settings -> Quality Profiles` and select "Android Lint".

I now run the build a second time, it runs the analysis and now when I go to my sonar page, all the issues disappeared. If I go to the "Issues" tab I see they're marked as removed.

Is this because of some setting I missed or misconfigured? Is there a way to 'have them back' or to tell Sonar not to mark them as removed?

---

**Update**: NOT changing Quality profile, the issues aren't touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, here is what happens @Stephan: your first analysis is done with the default "Sonar way" quality profile which relies on the embedded SonarSource Java analyser and you're getting some issues. Before the second analysis you're changing the quality profile to only rely on the "Android Lint" engine but without first executing this engine and so generating the Android Lint report. So for SonarQube there is no more issue and all the old ones are closed.

Comment: Yes, that is the scenario. How can i use the "Android Lint" profile from the start, then, since sonar.profile is deprecated? Is there a way to set it from the start, or is there a way to change it afterwards?

Comment: The documentation of this SonarQube Android Lint plugin was a bit misleading so I've updated it : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Android+Lint+Plugin. If you still have some open questions with this new version of the documentation, your feedback is highly welcome. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating the doc, but it doesn't cover my case. What I want to do is to analyse the project from the Jenkins build, without touching the build.gradle of the project. And I managed to do that, but what I don't know is to make it use the "Android Lint" quality profile from the start, even before the project has been analysed for the first time. Is this possible, given that the property "sonar.profile" is deprecated?

Comment: @Stephan, you must understand that the SonarQube Android Lint plugin doesn't execute anymore by itself the Android Lint engine (http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARANDRO-30). This feature was raising too many integration issues. So now, it's really your responsibility to execute the "Android Lint" engine.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can't run the Android Lint analysis from Jenkins and I must use the gradle plugin, modifying every project, is that so?

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm saying @Stephan. Let me try rephrasing : the SonarQube Android Lint plugin can only be used to consume an Android Lint report. Then it's up to you to define the best way to generalize the execution of this Android Lint engine on your Android projects

Comment: I find it very difficult to wrap my head around this. How should I execute the Android Lint engine in the first place then, if not through sonar-runner as a build step?

Comment: Checking it out as answer, but what I ended up doing was removing the analysis from Jenkins and putting it into the gradle file of each project

Comment: Sorry for retouching this, but would it be possible to update the [android project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/android/android-sonarqube-runner) in github linked by the docs? I find the documentation rather not very clear, and having a working gradle project to base my work on very helpful.

Comment: I think you're right @Stephan, our example should demonstrate how to generate this lint report from gradle and then how to reuse this lint report from SonarQube. Let's see what we can do.

Comment: if it's of any help, I managed to boil it down to this: https://gist.github.com/stepbeta/820f97990b2cc4a2b4f7